# How to take a float to a power of another float number?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sed, awk

I am trying to figure out how compute a math expression involving parenthesis and exponents in bash. Feel free to offer solutions using sed, awk, perl, bash

for example

```
 i=0.0545
 j=360
 (1+ $i * 2.43 / 100.0) ^ ($j/940) -1
```

How would you encoded in bash and get the floating point result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is in perl:

```
$ x=`perl -e 'print (1 + $ARGV[0] * 2.43 / 100.) ** ($ARGV[1] / 940.0) - 1' 0.0545 360.0`
$ echo $x
1.00132435
```

Comment: doesn't work when first argument is negative: perl -e 'print (1 + $ARGV[0] * 2.43 / 100.) ** ($ARGV[1] / 940.0) - 1' **-0.0545** 360 Results in: Unrecognized switch -0.0545* (-h will show valud options).

Comment: put `--` between the end of the perl script and the arguments: `perl -e 'print (1 + $ARGV[0] * 2.43 / 100.) ** ($ARGV[1] / 940.0) - 1' -- -0.0545 360`

Comment: Double dash means that the remaining arguments should be taken literally. Otherwise, an argument with a dash is treated as a flag (and its leading dash is stripped), and the next argument is treated as the argument to the prior flag. In this case, you want to treat the last two arguments as numbers which can possibly have negative signs (not dashes! Same ascii character, different semantic meaning).

Answer (score 5):

To calculate *x^n* use:

`bc -l <<< "e($n*l($x))"`

or

`echo "e($n*l($x))" | bc -l`

**Theory**

The `bc`command doesn't deal with exponentiation using float exponents. However, it has the exponencial `e()` and the logarithmic `l()` functions. Using these two functions, we can calculate the exponentiation by the property *x^n = exp(log(x^n)) = exp(n*log(x))*.

Answer (score 1):

I use `bc` for math when I need precision (but doesn't work in this case as it doesn't support fractional exponent):

```
echo "scale = 10; 1 / 3" | bc
```

Easiest is to go with `awk`:

```
$ echo "" | awk 'END {print (1+ 2.43/100.0) ^ (360/940) - 1}'
0.00923751
```

If you donno awk so much, you might need:

- http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/12473-pass-variable-awk.html
- http://www.google.com/search?q=pass+variable+to+awk

Comment: `bc` supports fractional exponents, you just have to remember that `a^b = exp(b * log(a))`. You can do it using `bc -l` with `define fpow(a, b) { return e(b * l(a)); }`.

Comment: Tidy trick.. thanks. Shows that it helps to pay attention in your math class.. :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_programming_language#An_equivalent_.27Power.27_function_in_GNU_bc

Answer (score 1):

(You might want to edit your post to include what you expect as the correct answer for your expression ;-)

Use awk. It needs a clue that you are expecting floating point calcs, so change any whole number expression parts to include a trailing `.0`  (as below).

```
i=0.0545  j=360 
awk 'BEGIN {     
  print "i=" '$i' "\tj=" '$j' "\texpr="(1.0+ '$i' * 2.43 / 100.0) ^ ('$j'/940.0) -1.0
}' /dev/null
# output 
i=0.0545        j=360   expr=0.000506991
```

Better yet, change BEGIN to END and use awk cmd-line var assignment, i.e.

```
awk 'END{
   print "i=" i "\tj=" j "\texpr="(1.0+ i * 2.43 / 100.0) ^ (j/940.0) -1.0
}' i=0.0545  j=360 /dev/null
#output    
i=0.0545        j=360   expr=0.000506991
```

(I think I've read recently that BEGIN won't process assignments on the cmd line, but it does work with END (obviously)).

I hope this helps.

Comment: how do I pass i and j from the outside of awk function?

Comment: See revised version. Good luck.

Comment: See revise #2. Also, interesting that we get 3 different answers for your expression. Which is the number you're expecting, OR ... ? :-) Good luck.